# How to paginate shopify app using Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app

I am working on a Shopify embedded app following the Shopify tutorial:

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-ruby-and-sinatra

I want to display orders table in my app but since there will be too many orders I need somekind of table with pages in my app.

I am really new to Ruby so I tried to achieve this with javascript only but I will have to load all orders which is what I want to avoid in the end.

Can someone guide me please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination is key. Will_paginate is a common gem for Ruby on Rails. If you can add gems to your Gemfile, look up will_paginate and include it in your file. Then you can paginate `Order` items like:

```
@orders = Order.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
```

And in your view.html.erb

```
<%= will_paginate @orders %>
```

It only loads the `per_page` amount of `@orders`. So it's fast and easy to setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply this really helped me this is how I did it :
require 'will_paginate/array' on top of the controller.
In my code :
`@orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })`
`@orders = @orders.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2)`
PS:
I don't know why people downvoted my question claiming It wasn't clear while If they were really familiar with the tags I included my question will be super clear for them.